# Sed replace specific line in file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I'm building a bash script for my virtual machine and I would like to know how to replace a specific line in this document:

```
[base]

## uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin
# autologin=dgod

## uncomment and set timeout to enable timeout autologin,

## the value should >=5

# timeout=10

## default session or desktop used when no systemwide config

# session=/usr/bin/startlxde
```

this line:

```
# autologin=dgod
```

I want to change to this

```
autologin=ubuntu
```

I have tried with "tee" and "sed" but couldn't make it work.
This should be very easy for someone who works with bash scripts more often than me.

Comment: `sed -i 's/^# autologin=.*/autologin=ubuntu/' /some/file`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is straightforward. Use the `s` command in `sed` to search and replace.

```
sed 's/# autologin=dgod/autologin=ubuntu/' /path/to/file
```

If you see what you want, add `-i` to change the file in place

```
sed -i 's/# autologin=dgod/autologin=ubuntu/' /path/to/file
```

Comment: the filename is /etc/lxdm/default.conf - so the full command should be like this? = sed -i 's/# autologin=dgod/autologin=ubuntu/' /etc/lxdm/default.conf

Comment: yes, exactly like that @lewis4u

Comment: No `/g` at the end?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie `g` means apply the command to every occurrence on the line specified, which is not relevant to this case

Comment: `sed 's/# 1/1' /etc/gai.conf` gives sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @Gulzar yes, you need a final `/` before your closing quote, i.e. `sed 's/# 1/1/' /etc/gai.conf`

Answer (score 5):

I've found the most effective way to do this is actually to use the change syntax to set the exact value you want unless you are explicitly trying to enable a two way toggle. You can use this to change as well as uncomment a line no matter how it is commented, with `#` or `//` or `<!--`.

`sed 's%searchTerm=% c searchTerm=desiredValue%' targetFile.txt`

Comment: You could mention that % is used to replace the / delimiter. Got me questioning my sanity for a while...